# How can I test if a Milo client connection to a server is actually using encryption?

Tags: java, iot, opc-ua

When using `Eclipse Milo` as a client, I want to test, after the connection has been established, if the connection is actually using encryption.

What is the best approach to do so?

Answer (score 1):

To truly verify you would need to look at Wireshark. Wireshark understands OPC-UA, so after configuring it to interpret the port of the server you're connected to as UA, you'll see all the messages show up as "UA Secure Conversation Message" or something along those lines. When encryption is not used you can actually see the type, full structure, and content of every message between client and server.